# Адаптивное меню

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scss

Добрый вечер, подскажите начинающему разработчику в чем проблема. В общем, нужно сделать, чтоб при определенном разрешении пункты меню группировались, я частично сделал, но при событии resize вкладка браузера зависает,  [вот что получилось](https://jsfiddle.net/gpgkcndu/2/), заранее спасибо за помощь

```js
$(function() {
  var menu = function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      if (!$('.nav__item').is('.nav__item_collapsed')) {
        $('<li class="nav__item nav__item_collapsed"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="nav__link">Items</a></li>')
          .insertAfter('.nav__item:first-child');
      }

      $('<div class="collapse"></div>').appendTo('.nav__item_collapsed');
      $('.nav__item').not('.nav__item_collapsed, .nav__item:first-child').appendTo('.collapse');

      $('.nav__item_collapsed').on('click', function() {
        $('.collapse').toggleClass('collapse_open');
      })
    }
  };

  menu();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    // menu();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: #272932;
}
.header {
  background-color: #42858c;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
.nav__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #272932;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.nav__link:hover {
  background-color: #F25F5C;
  color: #fff;
}
.collapse {
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.collapse_open {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Item 6</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: у вас `$('<div class="collapse"></div>').appendTo(` срабатывает тысячи раз при ресайзе, ресайс когда вы тащите мышкой срабатывает десятки раз, протестируйте как он работает, внутри события ресайз поставьте вывод в консоль чего-либо, это сообщение будет выведено 10-100 раз при одном перетаскивании ширины окна мышкой.

Comment: премного благодарен

Comment: @Jean-Claude Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `$('<div class="collapse"></div>').appendTo()` срабатывает тысячи раз при ресайзе. Происходящее внутри метода `resize()` срабатывает многократно (10..20..100), когда вы тащите окно мышкой

Протестируйте как он работает, внутри метода `resize()` поставьте вывод в консоль чего-либо, это сообщение будет выведено многократно при одном перетаскивании ширины окна мышкой.